# Sort and classify files using their name components (unix)

Tags: command-line, bash, files, sort

I have a folder with thousands of files respecting the following naming scheme:

> 'institute_model_scenario_river.txt'

Each components of the files names (institute, model, scenario, river) are variables.

Then, I would like to sort and classify those files by the name of each variables exept `'scenario'` and `'river'`.

Therefore, each institute name should be used to create a corresponding directory. These directories should be composed of sub-directories named accordingly with different 'model' names.

To be more accurate I would like to provide a small example, considering the following files:

```
wbm_gfdl_rcp4_mississippi.txt
matsiro_gfdl_rcp8_amazon.txt
wbm_miroc_rcp8_niger.txt
```

I would like to create a `'wbm'` directory having the sub-directories `'gfdl'` (containing the following file `'wbm_gfdl_rcp4_mississippi.txt'`) and `'miroc'` (containing the following file `'wbm_miroc_rcp8_niger.txt'`). And a `'matsiro'` directory having just a `'gfdl'` sub-directory (containing `'matsiro_gfdl_rcp8_amazon.txt'`).

Considering the huge amount of files, I don't really know from where to start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, you can split the file name to an array:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *_*_*_*.txt ; do
    IFS=_ arr=($file)
    dir=${arr[0]}/${arr[1]}
    [[ -d $dir ]] || mkdir -p "$dir"
    cp "$file" "$dir"/
done
```

If you want to move files instead of copy them, use `mv` instead of `cp`.